# Rudin Functional Analysis Chapter 6 Problem 10

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I am currently struggling to solve this problem:

Suppose 
$(f_i)$ 
is  a  sequence of locally  integrable  functions  in  $\omega$ (an open set in $\mathbb R$") and 
$\lim_i \int_K |f_i(x)|\,dx = 0$ 
for every compact $K$ in $\omega$

Prove that then $D^\alpha (f_i) \rightarrow 0$ in $D'(\omega)$ as i goes to infinity, $\forall$ multi-index $\alpha$

I have tried using the distribution definitions and the derivative of a distribution definition, but I am confused with the terminology and I don't see how to actually solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How far did you get? Remember that any test function $\varphi \in D(\omega)$ has bounded derivatives of all orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to show that $\int D^{\alpha} (f_i) \phi$ approaches $0.$ By definition of derivative this reduces to showing that $\int D^{\alpha} \phi (f_i)$ approaches $0.$ This is true because $D^{\alpha} \phi$ is bounded on its support $K.$